# What is that product he is using? The sphere I mean

Tags: electronics, microphones, production, equipment

[Imgur image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUHev.jpg)

I think it's used to put a microphone in it.

Comment: The left one (next to the mic he is holding) is a popfilter. Maybe the one in the front is one too. You can see an xlr-cable running behind it like there is another mic. But thats just a guess

Answer (score 1):

One of these I think.  The Kaotica Eyeball.   With a standard pop filter in front of it.

Remarkably expensive for a lump of foam.  Doubtless special hi-tec foam though.  Not any standard type you could get off-the-shelf from a foam manufacturer :-)

[image]

https://www.soundonsound.com/reviews/kaotica-eyeball